# accessing a single raster in a mosaic with Arcgis Python API

Tags: python, api, arcgis

I am connected to an ArcGIS portal and accessed an imagery service which is a mosaic dataset. I want to apply some raster functions only to a specific raster inside the mosaic but I can`t access them.

I am connected to an arcgis portal via

```
gis = GIS("https://portal", username="user", password="pwd")
```

I have access to an imagery service layer

```
lyr1 = gis.content.get('6be0d723157c46ada260d2649d94655f')

lyr1 = lyr1.layers[0]
```

now since this layer is a mosaic I would like to apply some raster functions. but only accessing specific rasters in the mosaic.

I`ve tried the query method

```
search_res = lyr1.query(where="OBJECTID=2834")
```

but it returns a `<class 'arcgis.features.feature.FeatureSet'>` and not an image service object

any tips? I can only use Python API on a jupyter notebook

Comment: what is the type of lyr1 when you run `print(type(lyr1))`?

Comment: lyr1 is <class 'arcgis.raster._layer.ImageryLayer'>
the problem is lyr1 is a collection of rasters and I want to access just one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`arcgis.raster.analytics.convert_feature_to_raster`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.raster.analytics.html#convert-feature-to-raster) to convert the FeatureSet to a imagery layer item.

```py
from arcgis.raster.analytics import convert_feature_to_raster
from arcgis.raster import ImageryLayer

#...

search_res = lyr1.query(where="OBJECTID=2834")
search_res_il = convert_feature_to_raster(search_res_df.sdf, 
                                   output_name='Search Raster', 
                                   output_raster_type='ImageryLayer', 
                                   gis=gis)
```